# Printing Matrix in Spiral Order

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print an array in spiral order (clockwise), but my code isn't printing things correctly.

My array is:

```
a = [
      [2,  4,  6,  8],
      [5,  9, 12, 16],
      [2, 11,  5,  9],
      [3,  2,  1,  8]
    ]
```

My solution:

```
def print_circ(arr, row, col)
  t = 0
  b = row - 1
  l = 0
  r = col - 1
  dir = 0
  while t <= b and l <= r do
    if dir == 0
      for i in l..r
        puts arr[t][i]
      end
      t += 1
    end
    if dir == 1
      for i in t..b
        puts arr[i][r]
      end
      r -= 1
    end
    if dir == 2
      for i in r..l
        puts arr[b][i]
      end
      b -= 1
    end
    if dir == 3
      for i in b..t
        puts arr[i][l]
      end
      l += 1
    end
    dir = (dir+1)%4
  end
end
```

When I run this, it doesn't print out the bottom or the left edges:

```
2
4
6
8
16
9
8
9
12
5
11
```

Can anyone please help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: In Ruby you should avoid C or Java style `for` loops, use iterators, which free you from caring about array limits. I have added a more Rubyesque solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bugs in your code are at `r..l` and `b..t`, where `r` is greater than `l`, and `b` is greater than `t`. When you define a range from a higher integer to a lower integer, the range is actually empty. For example:

```
irb> (0..3).to_a
 => [0, 1, 2, 3]
irb> (3..0).to_a
 => []
```

To fix your backwards iteration code, you can change the `for i in r..l` loop to `(l..r).reverse_each do |i| ... end`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on ranges in Ruby!

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but the proposed solution doesn't work: `(3..0).reverse_each.to_a` is empty, too. That's because `reverse_each` builds a temporary array based on `each` (which is already empty) and then iterates that (empty) array in reverse order.

Comment: @Stefan That's why I didn't propose `(3..0).reverse_each`. I proposed `(0..3).reverse_each`, with `l = 0` and `r = 3`, in this case. :)

Comment: @HengXiong your right, I've overlooked that you changed `r..l` to `l..r`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was already solved. I just wanted to provide a more idiomatic version of your code:

```
def each_spiral_value(arr)
  t = 0
  b = arr.size - 1
  l = 0
  r = arr.first.size - 1
  dir = [:right, :down, :left, :up].cycle

  while t <= b && l <= r
    case dir.next
    when :right
      l.upto(r) { |i| yield arr[t][i] }
      t += 1
    when :down
      t.upto(b) { |i| yield arr[i][r] }
      r -= 1
    when :left
      r.downto(l) { |i| yield arr[b][i] }
      b -= 1
    when :up
      b.downto(t) { |i| yield arr[i][l] }
      l += 1
    end
  end
end

each_spiral_value(a) { |v| puts v }
```

Changes:

- instead of being passed explicitly, `b` and `r` are calculated from the array's [`size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-size) and the size of its [`first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-first) element respectively
- the directional values were changed from numbers to symbols
- `dir` uses [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to create an enumerator that is cycled by calling [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)
- a `case` statement is used instead of multiple `if` statements
- `for` loops were replaced by [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and [`downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Integer.html#method-i-downto) loops
- printing the values was extracted from the method, the values are yielded instead (the caller decides what to do with it)

Instead of calling `next` manually, you could also pass a block to `cycle`. This would effectively replace your `while` loop:

```
[:right, :down, :left, :up].cycle do |dir|
  break if t > b || l > r
  case dir
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `downto` in the decreasing loops.

Here is your code fixed:

```
def print_circ(arr, row, col)
  t = 0
  b = row - 1
  l = 0
  r = col - 1
  dir = 0

  while t <= b and l <= r do

    if dir == 0
      for i in l..r
        puts arr[t][i]
      end
      t += 1
    end

    if dir == 1
      for i in t..b
        puts arr[i][r]
      end
      r -= 1
    end

    if dir == 2
      for i in r.downto(l)
        puts arr[b][i]
      end
      b -= 1
    end

    if dir == 3
      for i in b.downto(t)
        puts arr[i][l]
      end
      l += 1
    end

    dir = (dir+1)%4

  end

end

print_circ([[2,4,6,8],[5,9,12,16],[2,11,5,9],[3,2,1,8]], 4, 4)
```

Comment: I am not sure who answered first here, as I edited the code because of a mis-alignment. Oh well...

Comment: Thanks for the information on downto! @heng used the reverse_each method, but I was just wondering if you can also implement downto in the .each do loops? If so, would you mind sharing an example?

Comment: `for i in r.downto(l)` – the combination for `for` and `downto` looks odd to me. Since `downto` already provides iteration, you should simply use `r.downto(l) do |i|`.